# How to show time format

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, bloc

I want to show only its time without date, so that my chart can be displayed perfectly.
while I want the date only shows time like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime now = DateTime.now(); //Set your datetime value
String formattedDate = DateFormat('kk:mm').format(now);
```

Comment: Note that `kk` will format midnight as `24`, so the above code would format 12:30 AM as 24:30, which (IMO) is a little unusual.  Most people probably would use `HH`.

Comment: Yes that's true. More functional to use as HH